# Verify that a set is open

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $U_0\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\}$ defined as follows: $$U_0=\big\{(x_0,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\}\;|\; x_0\ne 0\big\}.$$

> **I must prove that $U_0$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\}$**

**My attempt.** Consider the function $$f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\}\to \mathbb{R}\quad\text{defined as}\quad f(x_0,\dots, x_n)=x_0.$$

We observe that $f$ is continuous, then since $$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\}\setminus f^{-1}\big(\{0\}\big)=U_0,$$
we have that $U_0$ is open.

> **Question.** It's correct? If yes, there is a more hasty way?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $\mathbb R^{n + 1} - \{0\})$? Is it $\mathbb R^{n + 1} \setminus \{(0, \ldots, 0)\}$? If so, then it's not closed.

Comment: Yes. But $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\})=\{0_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. Alternatively, observe $U_0=\left\{\Bbb R^{n+1}-\{0_{\Bbb R^{n+1}}\}\right\}\cap(\Bbb R-\{0\}\times\Bbb R^n)$, the latter is a product of open sets, hence open.